# How to pass query parameters in axios

Tags: api, vue.js, axios

I want to send a request to http://localhost:5000/trackers/{{id}}. I tried to pass parameters through axios, but when i checked the API the request went only to http://localhost:5000/trackers/. How can I fix this?

Axios code:

```
mounted() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:5000/trackers/', {params : { id } })
    .then((resp ) => console.log(resp.data))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err.response))
    let id = localStorage['id'] 
    return{
        id
    }
```

How to pass the query parameters through axios
This is my API code:
[image]
I still haven't created a route for '/trackers/{{id}}' in my API. I first tried to check if the routing in my VueJS code is working.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to request `http://localhost:5000/trackers/{{id}}`,

you can build the request url like this:

```js
...
  axios.get('http://localhost:5000/trackers/' + id)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try once with the following code?

```
mounted() {
    axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/trackers/${id}`)
    .then((resp ) => console.log(resp.data))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err.response))
    let id = localStorage['id'] 
    return{
        id
    }
}
```